# Mask input for time(`01:55`)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want mack a mask input for time(`01:55`) without use plugin,as only accept to user typed four number, (i mean, when user type number `01` put after it this `:` and next user type `55`), how is it?

This is my code that not work:

```
<input name="text" class="time">


$('.time').live('keyup change',function(){
    this.value = this.value.replace(^[0-1]?[0-9]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}, "")
});
```

Here is full code: http://jsfiddle.net/yGLsH/

Comment: Why don't you want to use plugins ? The masked input plugin does exactly what you want.